# Excel VBA Timeout Error -2147012894

Tags: vba, excel, timeout, salesforce

I was trying to make REST call to SFDC from Excel VBA (using oauth2) but every time I got error message "Error : -2147012894 - Timeout Error" on "Http1.send" line. Below code is working fine on another machine. Both machine have 
Excel 2007
Windows 7

Code :

```
Dim Http1 As Object
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/opportunity/describe"
On Error GoTo errorHandler
Set Http1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Http1.Open "GET", URL, False
Http1.setTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
Http1.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & GetSetting("SF", "Tokens", "AccessKey") 'accesstoken
Http1.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
Http1.send
Set retrieveData = Http1
Set Http1 = Nothing
Exit Function

errorHandler:
MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.description
```

Please help, if anyone have come across this type of error. Much Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have all the references you need set correctly?

Comment: Maybe a proxy must be set? `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` does not use system default proxy settings. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290761 or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. 
@Sam : As far as I know all the references I need are set correctly and its working fine in many systems except few ones.

Comment: @Axel: Thanks for looking, I also tried to set proxy setting in above request, but nothing happen, Error still persist.

Comment: I also did some finding and come to know that from these machine(facing above error) web service didn't gets called. That's why after waiting specific amount of time it shows above error.